# JXS if else class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
{item.status}
<div className="{item.status !== '' ? 'hide' : ''} pull-right">Content</div>
```

Why above jsx has no effect? My item.status value is string. But in my DOM I can't see hide class been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have wrapped your ternary operator in " so it is treated as string. Try this instead:

```
{item.status}
<div class={"pull-right "+(item.status !== '' ? 'hide' : '')}>Content</div>
```

Comment: what if I want to use if else condition instead of adding the hide class?

Comment: you can wrap the entire component in the ternary operator e.g. {item.status !== '' ?null:<div class="pull-right ">Content</div>}

Answer (score 0):

Beside what @rahul-pratap-singh said, consider using nice, tiny package called `classnames` - [link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) so you can use it like:

```
import classes from 'classnames';

// later on 
<div className={classes({
    "pull-right": true,
    "hide": item.status !== '',
})} />
```

I think it leads to much cleaner code than joining string.

Or at least use es6 string interpolation - [link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
// instead of 
"pull-right "+(item.status !== '' ? 'hide' : '')

// with string interpolation
`pull-right ${item.status.length ? '' : 'hide'}`;
```